# Codeigniter: This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

i'm doing a simple thing saving some content in database, but some how i'm getting this  HTTP ERROR 500.  I don't know why it is coming and my code is also not working properly. Please have a look

```
Controller.php
    function register_query()
        {
            //load the registration helper under helper folder
            $this->load->helper('registration');


            $this->form_validation->set_rules('first_name', 'Name', 'required');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('message1', 'Message', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'required');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
            {
                $data = array(
                'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
                'message1' => $this->input->post('message1'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                );

            }
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && $this->Register_Model->register_query($data))
            { 
                    $data['success'] = "Your Query has been sent successfully... !!";
                $this->load->view('contact',$data);
            }
        else
        {
                    $data['success'] = "Your Query has not been sent successfully... !!";
                $this->load->view('contact',$data);
            }

        }

Model.php
    public function query($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('queries', $data);

        $id = $this->db->insert_id();

        return (isset($id)) ? $id : FALSE;      
    }
```

Comment: did you check your logs ?

Comment: yes sir i have.. @ArunpandianM can you tell me about my code if it is correct or not?

Comment: try @RiggsFolly 's answer need logs so that it would be easy to find the error

Comment: basically the cause for 500 (internal server errors) are basically php FATAL error, which occurs due to function name not found. Quick check would be, are you loading the *model* and *libraries* properly?

Comment: @cyberrspiritt absolutely sir. you were right model was not loading properly and second thing i need to know is if you keep the same name of your function in controller and in model can this also cause error 500?

Comment: @dawood it wouldnt produce an error. Certainly not 500.

Comment: @cyberrspiritt thanyou sir because of you my error was removed and i love you for that :) there was also a model name mistake in my code

Comment: @dawood: You're welcome. Do upvote my comment or mark it as accepted to help other fellows stuck in the same situation.

Comment: @cyberrspiritt i have upvoted the comment sir and sir i have a problem here. When i open my website some of its tab don't load. means i have added two options in my tab one is contact us and 2nd is payment when they don't load when i close the chrome and open the website again. after opening anyother page on website these two options gets load. can you help mw with that?

Comment: @dawood: make a new question about it and ping me the url for the question created

Comment: @cyberrspiritt https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45387212/header-php-is-not-loading-changes-when-open-first-time

Answer (score 3):

you need to give us more info that just a 500 response code. check your error-log, and update your question.

For the best error logging experience, set error_reporting to -1, turn display_errors off, and set a custom error_log. Then in the terminal, type `tail -f /path/to/error_log`. Your notices, warnings and errors will now scroll past in real time, without distorting your web page's display.

the quick way is to have `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the top of your script.

Comment: let me try it..!!

Comment: go for it! :-) post your error

Comment: ini_set('display_errors', 1);  this worked to get logs

Comment: @sunilKV its not the best way, any notices or warnings will stop any `header()` calls from happening, that's why its best to have it off and tail the log in your terminal instead