# header.php is not loading changes when open first time

Tags: php

I have searched this thing and i could not find the answer i have a issue here. I have a website when i have made some changes some of them are done but i have some issue in some of my updates. like i have added 2 options contact us and payment. after uploading the file on the server when i visit the website it doesn't show me these two options but after when i visit any page on the website and check on the tab these options the changes are loaded. I hope you got my point.. can anyone help me?

Comment: Please share some source code to have a look into

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely be caching. Your browser is loading the cached version of the page.

You could try to load the page in incognito mode / private mode.
Or you could hard refresh.